# Source não é reconhecido como comando interno

Tags: path

Ao tentar ativar uma virtual com o comando `source venv/bin/activate`, aparece a mensagem:

`source não é reconhecido como comando interno`.

Tudo isso no console do *PyCharm*.

Comment: Você utiliza Linux?

Answer (score 1):

O comando activate tem a finalidade de ativar um ambiente virtual anteriormente criado, se você já possui um ambiente vitual criado, configurado e deseja ativa-lo o comando é:

```
activate nome_do_ambiente
```

Senão recomendo os seguintes steps:

1. Instalar o gerenciador de ambientes conda.
2. Executar o comando para criação do ambiente via conda com a versão do Python desejada (no caso coloquei 3.6):

   `conda create -n nome_do_ambiente python=3.6`
3. Acessar o ambiente criado via o comando:

   `activate nome_do_ambiente`

Obs: Para que os passos acima seja executados com sucesso é necessária uma instalação correta do **Python** ou **Anaconda** e que a pasta scripts exemplo: **C:\Users\joao\Anaconda3\Scripts** esteja na **variavél de ambiente path** caso o sistema seja **Windows**

Answer (score 0):

Se não estou enganado o console do **PyCharm** executa o **Python** em modo interativo e não a *shell* do sistema operacional. O `source` é justamente um dos comandos internos do **Bash**, daí o comando não ser reconhecido.

O **PyCharm** tem seu próprio modo de implementar ambientes virtuais e que podem ser utilizados de forma global ou específica dentro dos projetos. Para maiores detalhes sobre como fazê-lo, consulte o tópico [Configuring Python Interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html.html) do manual.